# Thread safety for Double-checked locking in Kotlin - synchronized(this), synchronized(xxx::class) or synchronized(xxx::class.java)

Tags: android, multithreading, kotlin

I have a Kotlin code

```
abstract class XXXRoomDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    companion object {
        @Volatile
        private var instance: XXXRoomDatabase? = null
        private const val name = "xxx"

        fun instance(): XXXRoomDatabase {
            if (instance == null) {
                synchronized(this) {
                    if (instance == null) {
                        instance = databaseBuilder(
                            XXXApplication.instance,
                            XXXRoomDatabase::class.java,
                            name
                        ).build()
                    }
                }
            }
            return instance!!
        }
    }
}
```

For the `synchronized` statement, to achieve truly thread safety, should it be

1. `synchronized(this)`
2. `synchronized(XXXRoomDatabase::class)`
3. `XXXRoomDatabase(XXXRoomDatabase::class.java)`

May I know, which is the correct approach?

Thanks.

Comment: A common practise is to use a dedicated lock object like `private val sLockObject = Object()` & synchronize that. Using `synchronized(this)` and the other class synchronizing can prevent access to other methods & variables (I guess) if you'd be in a multi-threaded env.